# Wordpress DB SQL SELECT query with variable returning empty array

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am using wordpress to develop a site. I am creating a CPT by taking data direct from the database. The idea is that I will create a CPT from the WP DB. If the CPT is empty it will retrieve all data to populate and create the CPT instances. However, if the CPT already has instances it will check the meta_id of the CPT against the DB and see what's missing. I was then hoping it would pass them missing DB data into the CPT therefore not updating the whole CPT each time.

The 1st function check_for_cpt_external_authors() gets the CPT meta ids
The 2nd function query_external_author_table() accepts the above ids. If empty it gets all the data to populate the CPT else compare meta id with DB and see whats missing.
The third function insert_into_auto_cpt() takes the result of 2nd function and populates the CPT.

Everything works as expected apart from the else section of the 2nd function. The following query does not appear to pick missing meta ids - `` $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE "authors_%_authors_name" AND `meta_id` NOT IN ( $meta_ids )'); ``

Any advice would be much appreciated. Also I assume this hook should run on init so it is ran every time the page loads or is refreshed.

```
/*
* Action to run all functions below
*/
add_action( 'admin_init', 'insert_into_auto_cpt', 11 );

/*
 * Get all External Authors in one array by title(name)
 */
function check_for_cpt_external_authors() {
    $cpt_meta_id_arr = array();

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'external-authors',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $cpt_meta_id_arr[] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_id', true );
    }
    return $cpt_meta_id_arr;
}

/*
 * Get external authors from DB
 *
 * If CPT external authors empty then get from DB, else if CPT then check against DB for any not in CPT.
 */
function query_external_author_table($available_in_cpt_array) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( NULL === $available_in_cpt_array || 0 === $available_in_cpt_array || '0' === $available_in_cpt_array
         || empty( $available_in_cpt_array ) ) {
        $results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `'. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE "authors_%_authors_name" GROUP BY `meta_value`');
        return $results;
    } else {
        $meta_ids = implode( ",", $available_in_cpt_array );
        print_r($meta_ids);
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE "authors_%_authors_name" AND `meta_id` NOT IN ( $meta_ids )');
        echo '---------------------------------------------- Reached ELSE Statement -----------------------------------------------------';
        return $results;
    }
}

/*
 * Enter external authors into CPT
 */
function insert_into_auto_cpt() {

    $available_in_cpt_array = check_for_cpt_external_authors();
    $database_results = query_external_author_table($available_in_cpt_array);

    if ( NULL === $database_results || 0 === $database_results || '0' === $database_results || empty( $database_results ) ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ( $database_results as $result ) {
        $external_author = array(
            'post_title' => $result->meta_value,
            'post_type'   => 'external-authors',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_input' => array(
                'meta_id'        => $result->meta_id,
            ),
        );
        wp_insert_post( $external_author );
    }
}
```

Comment: You have your variable inside the single quote string. In PHP variables can only be called like that when you're using a double quoted string. `$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE "authors_%_authors_name" AND `meta_id` NOT IN ( ' . $meta_ids . ' )');`

Comment: Also be careful with using variables like that if you are handling user input, if lets say the $meta_id can be giving through the URL parameters then it will leave you with some serious vulnerabilities - Take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: Questions about WordPress development are much more likely to be answered on [wordpress.se].